# remove XML line breaks in javascript/asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

reading XML from asp file and taking the response into javascript variable, we are getting XML with line breaks.
below is the code iam using.

```
var s = <% response.write getDefaultProductArea().xml %>;
```

Response:

```
 var s = <productarea>
<name>OneSite</name>
<logo width="130" height="34">/multishell_cb/images/products/onesite.png</logo>
<tabset>onesite.xml</tabset>
<actionbar>defaultOnesite.xml</actionbar>
<show-if/>
<default-if>default</default-if>
    </productarea>;
```

but we need the XML value in single line as shown below.

```
var s = ' <productarea> <name>OneSite</name><logo width="130" height="34">/multishell_cb/images/products/onesite.png</logo><tabset>onesite.xml</tabset><actionbar>defaultOnesite.xml</actionbar><show-if/><default-if>default</default-if></productarea>';
```

Please suggest...

Comment: Why you need XML in single line? What is difference? And it's not answer, but why do not use ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = '<% response.write Replace(getDefaultProductArea().xml, vbCrLf, "") %>';
```